User defined XPath operators in XSLT
I have an function that would look much nicer as an operator.
We can use append as an example, lets say I want to use +
so
$foo + $bar
rather than
array:append($foo,$bar)
There is nothing obvious that I could find. I strongly suspect this isn't possible.

It is certainly not possible in XPath 3.1, the latest and current version of XPath, to overload an operator. I am currently not sure whether something like that was considered for 4.0 in the ongoing development work.

well, I wasnt so much wanting to overload as simply define a new one, but I'm splitting hairs thanks

I used the term overload because that's the conceptual name I know from e.g. C++ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading. Let's wait whether Michael Kay or someone else working on XPath 4 comes along to tell us whether anything is planned for the new version.

The only new feature for operators in general I find is fn:op https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xpath-functions-40/Overview.html#func-op. But that is not meant to allow you to overload or add new operators, just to give you the flexibility to call an operator as a function.

ah the irony is I want the opposite (that does exist in other languages) where you take a binary function and you use it as an operator

There is no such capability in the 3.0/3.1 specs. You could add it as a 4.0 request at https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs, but you'll have to put forward a strong argument. My suspicion is that it's much harder to do in a weakly typed language, especially one that has a lot of implicit type coercions.

the mechanism would be to simply identify some predefined pattern, so for example in ML languages you can usually take a function wrap it in '(' and ')' and then use it as an operator - I'd have to look up the precise mechanism, I suspect '('/')' may be problematic, and my motivation is quite esoteric, so I may not raise anything unless it comes pressing.

I've seen two different mechanisms in other languages: one allows you to overload existing operators applying them to new types of operands, the other allows you to define new operator symbols. Either of these would be quite difficult to achieve in XPath, (a) because of the type coercion rules, and (b) because nearly all the ASCII characters have been used, often heavily overloaded. For example [1] + [2] is already allowed and gives 3.
